# GitLab Backups Auto Cleanup

Tags: gitlab

I have scheduled GitLab backups through crontab which backs up gitLab data everyday at 2 AM.
The problem I have is cleaning up of backup files automatically. Backups files have now been piling up and I want to automate this task.

Uncommenting the following lines in 'gitlab.rb' doesn't help.

gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800

For your info, my GitLab has been installed with omnibus package on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 5):

After editing `gitlab.rb`, you need to run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` to make your changes take effect.

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate that. New to Gilab and Linux environment so going through lot of troubles.

Comment: I now have another issue,  'gitlab-ctl reconfigure' fails with following message: Recipe Compile Error in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb
 NameError
  ---------
  uninitialized constant Module::SSLCertificateFile
  
  Cookbook Trace:
  ---------------
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:35:in `from_file'

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your config file. You could try to run it with an empty file (or everything commented out).

Comment: When you say config file, do you mean gitlab.rb?

Comment: Yes, that is the one.